# Why Firebase transactions slow?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function which runs every time when a new document (participation in an event) is created by a user. I use transactions because in some cases new participation documents created very quickly after eachother and i want to avoid race conditions. But in this way this function usually takes 40-120 seconds to run.

```
export const esLatDailyAggr = async (
  uid: admin.firestore.DocumentReference,
  eventTypeId: admin.firestore.DocumentReference,
  timestamp: Date,
  clientId: admin.firestore.DocumentReference,
  year: number,
  month: number,
  day: number) => {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  console.log("Starting to update daily aggr data.");
  const docId = `${uid.id}-${year}-${month}-${day}`; // create composite key

  const statsRefAggr = admin.firestore().collection("dailyAggregateData");
  const queryAggr = statsRefAggr.doc(docId);
  await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
    const queryAggrSnapshot = await transaction.get(queryAggr);

    if (!queryAggrSnapshot.exists) { // check if document exists
      console.log(
        docId, " Daily doc not found. Creating new one by new Participation");
      // create new document with composite key
      transaction.set(queryAggr, {
        uid: uid,
        year: year,
        month: month,
        day: day,
        NoOfParticipations: 1,
        ActiveClientsId: [clientId],
        ActiveEventTypeId: [eventTypeId],
        timestamp: timestamp,
      });
    } else {
      // update existing document
      transaction.update(queryAggr, {
        NoOfParticipations: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        ActiveClientsId: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(clientId),
        ActiveEventTypeId: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(eventTypeId),
      });
      console.log(docId, " Daily aggr data updated by new Participation.");
    }
  });
  const endTime = Date.now();
  console.log("Daily Aggr Data function finished. Running Time: ",
  endTime - startTime, "ms");
};
```

Is there any way to make it significantly faster?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to optimize your function but one way to make it significantly faster is to `return` each statement that you're executing. e.g:

```
transaction
.set(queryAggr, {
    uid: uid,
    year: year,
    month: month,
    day: day,
    NoOfParticipations: 1,
    ActiveClientsId: [clientId],
    ActiveEventTypeId: [eventTypeId],
    timestamp: timestamp,
})
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    const endTime = Date.now();
    console.log("Daily Aggr Data function finished. Running Time: ",
    endTime - startTime, "ms");

    return;
});
```